# How to get list of tables, that don`t have a specific column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I need to have a list of tables in MySQL, that don`t have a column 'created' or 'modified', so I can add them if non existant. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help / hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query INFORMATION_SCHEMA database for this.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema.html

Comment: Thanks. The following query did the trick: SELECT c.table_name, COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.`TABLES` t INNER JOIN information_schema.`COLUMNS` c ON t.table_name = c.table_name
where column_name =  'created'
OR column_name = 'modified'  //for those interested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from PHP. Connect to the database and browse the mysql table. It will have all table definitions, then run `DESCRIBE` on each table, that will get you the structure.

I can give you some code examples if you like

Comment: Thanks, but PHP is not an option.